# Laravel validation, dynamic date

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to have a dynamic date for a commitment date?

For example, we can hire a person **1 year in the future** and **commitment dates start in 2008 minimum**

I have this for now? I don't like it

```php
'date_commitment' => 'required|date|after:2008-12-31|before:2021-01-01'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't like`?

Comment: @CaddyDZ: Ie that each 2 years, I have to change the date `before:2021-01-01'` it's not good.I want to limit automatically on  2 years

Comment: `'before:' . date('Y') + 2 . '-01-01'` would output 2023 two years from now

Comment: You're welcome, I made my comment an answer if you're willing to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concatenate the current year using the `date` function

```php
'date_commitment' => 'required|date|after:2008-12-31|before:' . date('Y') + 2 . '-01-01'
```

would output `2021` now
would output `2023` two years from now

Answer (score 0):

working here.

```
$end_date =date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->input('start-date').'+ 240 day'));

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[                          
                        
            'start-date'    => 'required',               
                    
            'end-date'  => 'required|date|after:'.$request->input('start-date').'|before:'.$end_date.'',                
                        
            
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

now you can user by jQuery :
$('#end-date').datepicker(
{
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
maxDate:0,
beforeShow: function() {
$(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#start-date').val());
$(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#end-date').val());
if($('#start-date').val() === '') $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 0); }
});